# Compare row and column and print the matched column

Tags: python, linux

I have two files and I wanna compare the rows of 1st file to the column of second file and print the values in the matched column. For instance:

File 1:

```
Name
age
weight
```

File 2:

```
Name,gender,age,height
Aaa,F,25,150
Bb,M,27,145
Cc,M,32,178
```

Desired output:

```
Name,age
Aaa,25
Bb,27
Cc,32
```

Comment: What have you tried? Any specific issues you have?

Comment: I am new to programming.. I wanted to know any easy way to do this task

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say but you should start by learning to program.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick script without 3 party libraries:

```py
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Reading file.
    rows = f.read()
    # Getting available items in file2.txt
    rows = rows.splitlines()
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Reading file.
    data = f.read()
    # Getting data as csv rows
    data = [_.split(',') for _ in data.splitlines()]
    # First row is for headers
    headers = data[0]
    # Set data.
    data_dicts = [dict(zip(headers, _)) for _ in data[1:]]
    # Print first result: headers
    print(','.join(h for h in headers if h in rows))
    # Print rows with available data.
    for row in data_dicts:
        print(','.join(v for k, v in row.items() if k in rows))
```